# Why would the quota command not work at all?

Tags: command-line, quota

I've installed and then updated `quota`, and now whenever I try and run the command, this is what happens:

```
superuser@superuser-MS-....:~$ quota -v
superuser@superuser-MS-....:~$ quota
superuser@superuser-MS-....:~$ quota -s
```

nothing. Does anyone have any idea why this could be?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you don't have any quota set for the user `superuser` on the mounted filesystems in `/etc/mtab` and NFS share (if any).

Have a check:

```
% quota
% quota -s
% quota -v
% quota -f /        
quota: Mountpoint (or device) / not found or has no quota enabled.
quota: Not all specified mountpoints are using quota.
```